# Is "Bitwise Complement Operator" (~ tilde) distributive?

Tags: logic, propositional-logic, mathematical-foundations, mathematical-analysis, bit-manipulation

To be more precise, Is `~(a+b) = ~a + ~b`? Here, `"~"` bitwise NOT operator.

I ran into this question while thinking about the 2's complement, which adds `1` to `~x` (i.e., `-x = ~x + 1`).

Suppose we are given `-x` (in binary), and we need to find `x` (in binary). We can do this by computing `x = ~(-x-1)`, but computing `-x-1` (by hand) is a bit of a hassle when compared to computing `~(-x)` (easy to flip bits directly). So, I wanted to find some relation between `~(-x)` and `x` that can help me calculate `x`.

It turns out that `~(-x) = x-1`. I found this relation by taking some examples.

But I wanted to derive this relation. This was my derivation approach:

```bash
-x = ~x + 1        # from 2's complement definition
~(-x) = ~(~x + 1)  # applying bitwise NOT on both sides
~(-x) = x + ~1     # taking bitwise NOT into the brackets: ~(~x) = x.
~(-x) = x - 2      # ~1 = -2
```

This above result is incorrect (it should be `x-1` instead of `x-2`).

What mistake did I make? Can we take "~" within the brackets (step 3)? If not, what would correct derivational steps look like?

Comment: As you pointed out, if `x` is an integer, then `~x = -x-1`. Therefore `~(a+b) = -a-b-1`, but `~a+~b = -a-1-b-1 = -a-b-2`. In conclusion, `~(a+b) = ~a+~b+1`

Comment: `-x = ~x + 1 = ~(x - 1)` are each a definition of two's complement negation, you can probably derive one from the other but they also just .. exist

Comment: Try a few examples, plugging in concrete values for a, b, x, and I think should have a much better idea of the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not. By De Morgan's law,

$$\lnot(a\lor b)=(\lnot a)\land(\lnot b)\\\ne(\lnot a)\lor(\lnot b)$$

and this carries to the bitwise case.

---

Adding one to a binary number is virtually as easy as flipping: start from the right, flip the bit and if was a $1$, carry to the next.